# Where to find common app icons like username, password, email in Android drawable resources

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-icons

Okay, this may seem like a silly question to you but I want to have icons inside EditText fields in an activity in Android for a login/registration form. 
[image]
I want to ask whether I could find official Android icons for this purpose? I've already browsed `\sdk\platforms\<api-version>\data\res\drawable-hdpi` folders but was unable to find those icons. Maybe is it me or should there be a well-defined documentation available for at least common icons like the ones I require. Thank you in advnace.

Answer (score 1):

There are some common Android assets at the [Android Design](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) website. You probably would like the "[Action Bar Action Pack](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)" which is previewed [here](http://wireframesketcher.com/mockups/android-action-bar-icons.html).

Comment: I did download and went through the Action bar icon pack from Android but the icons I require (name, username/email, password) were not in there and after extensive search in the various API versions of the SDK, I can't seem to find them there, either.